# Constructor que acepta un objeto

Tags: javascript

tengo este problema que no puedo resolver

```
  // Crea una Clase de ES6 o una función constructor llamada "Usuario"
  // Debe aceptar un objeto "opciones" con las propiedades "usuario", "nombre", "email" y "password"
  // En el `contructor`, define el usuario, el nombre, el email y la contraseña
  // El `contructor` debe tener un método llamado "saludar" en su `prototype` que devuelva una string 'Hola, mi nombre es {{nombre}}'
  // {{nombre}} debe ser el nombre definido en cada instancia
  // Devuelve la clase
  // Tu código:
    

 
      function Usuario(usuario,nombre,email,password) {
        this.usuario = usuario;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
      }
      
    
    Usuario.prototype.saludar = function() {
      return 'Hola, mi nombre es' + this.nombre

    }
    const NuevoUsser = new Usuario ("GDA", "Pablo", "G@hola", "3")
    return NuevoUsser
  }
```

Creo que estoy interpretando mal el problema pero a su vez cuando quiero pasar los test me dice "Usuario no es un constructor". Si alguno me puede ayudar

Comment: Yo probé tu código y funciona, deberías revisar de nuevo

Comment: Hola @Snowi ¿podrías compartir también un poco como estás corriendo los test y cuando te arroja ese error? sería útil

Comment: Si te falla, intenta usar `class` [Echa un vistazo](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_classes.asp)

Comment: Amigo enrealidad alli no estas definiendo un objeto `options` que se le pueda pasar al constructor si no mas bien usando la clase como el objeto `options` en si.

Answer (score 0):

```
    function crearUsuario() {
  // Crea una Clase de ES6 o una función constructor llamada "Usuario"
  // Debe aceptar un objeto "opciones" con las propiedades "usuario", "nombre", "email" y "password"
  // En el `contructor`, define el usuario, el nombre, el email y la contraseña
  // El `contructor` debe tener un método llamado "saludar" en su `prototype` que devuelva una string 'Hola, mi nombre es {{nombre}}'
  // {{nombre}} debe ser el nombre definido en cada instancia
  // Devuelve la clase
  // Tu código:
  function Practica(opciones){
       this.nombre = opciones.nombre;
       this.usuario = opciones.usuario;
       this.email = opciones.email;
       this.password = opciones.password;
  }
  Practica.prototype.saludar = function() {
    return 'Hola, mi nombre es ' + this.nombre;
  }
  return Practica;
}
/*Lo de Usuario  que dice antes el test creara la variable y lo igualara a la función principal*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Estoy seguro que con esto pasas el test, si tienes dudas que no se han aclarado en los cometarios solo avisa.

```js
  function crearUsuario() {
  // Tu código:
  class Usuario {
 //Creo la clase
    constructor(opciones) { // El constructor acepta el objeto opciones con sus propiedades
//se define el "usuario"
      this.usuario = opciones.usuario;
      this.nombre = opciones.nombre;
      this.email = opciones.email;
      this.password = opciones.password;
      this.saludar = function () { //funcion saludar
        return `Hola, mi nombre es ${this.nombre}`;
      };
    }

  }
  return Usuario; // se retorna la clase
}

//Asi se deberia usar 
const Usuario = crearUsuario();
const edgar = {
  usuario : "DonFierro",
  nombre : "Adrian",
  email : "email@hotmail.com",
  password : 123456
}
const user = new Usuario(edgar)
```